# Get single row from this duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I want to display one row but with duplicate data conditions,

How can I select a single record based on the last date and cif_awal?

```
SELECT *
FROM tableCompare
WHERE CIF_AWAL = 301800150001911'
ORDER BY TGL_KONTRAK DESC;
```

[image: data_duplicate]

```
301800150001911 |   2.01516+12  |   3.018052+14 |   840920150654    |   2017-03-20
301800150001911 |   2.01516+12  |   3.018052+14 |   840920150654    |   2016-11-08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RowNumber` with `Partition by` like this:

```
select * from (
SELECT *, RowNumber() over(partition by CIF_AWAL order by TGL_KONTRAK desc) as rw 
FROM tableCompare where CIF_AWAL in ( '301800150001911')--you can add many cif_awal and get lastest record for each one
) t where t.rw=1
```

but if you have just one `CIF_AWAL`, simply just use this:

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM df 
WHERE CIF_AWAL = 301800150001911 
order by Cast(TGL_KONTRAK as Date) desc
```

Comment: @faisalalfarisy, if it answers your question, please mark it as answer. It will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM df 
WHERE CIF_AWAL = 301800150001911 
order by Date(TGL_KONTRAK) desc 
limit 1
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is not a T-SQL Operator; this will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach of picking maximum date for CIF_AWAL and using it in JOIN.

```
;WITH CTE_CIF_MAXDATE AS
(
SELECT CIF_AWAL ,MAX(TGL_KONTRAK) as TGL_KONTRAK
FROM tableCompare
GROUP BY CIF_AWAL 
)
SELECT t.*
FROM tableCompare as t
INNER JOIN CTE_CIF_MAXDATE  as c
ON c.TGL_KONTRAK = t.TGL_KONTRAK 
AND c.CIF_AWAL = t.CIF_AWAL
```